# what does "assume" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Banks are already passing on increased costs to certain customers, and insurance companies are assuming incremental risks to compensate for negative yields.

source:http://www.businessinsider.com/global-negative-bond-yields-2016-5

Comment: ***To assume:***
2. to take upon oneself; undertake or take on or over (a position, responsibility, etc), http://www.thefreedictionary.com/assume

Answer (score 1):

'Assuming' in this context means 'Taking on'.